# Issues sharing folder through NFS - RPC: Unable to send; errno = Bad file descriptor or Program not registered

Tags: macos, high-sierra, nfs

I'm using Mac OS High Sierra 10.13, and I'm facing some issues sharing a folder through NFS.

## The configuration:

Built-in firewall is disabled and there is no third party firewall installed.

1. I made sure the **nfs service** is **enabled**:

   ```
   $ sudo nfsd enable
   ```

   > The nfsd service is already enabled.
2. I made sure the **nfs service** is **running**:

   ```
   $ sudo nfsd start
   ```

   > The nfsd service is already running.
3. I checked with nmap to see ports being listened to:

   ```
   $ nmap localhost
   ```

   ```
           
   Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-17 21:53 CEST
   Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
   Host is up (0.00034s latency).
   Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1 10.101.97.98
   Not shown: 995 filtered ports
   PORT     STATE SERVICE
   80/tcp   open  http
   111/tcp  open  rpcbind
   1021/tcp open  exp1
   1023/tcp open  netvenuechat
   2049/tcp open  nfs


   Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.34 seconds
   ```
4. rpcinfo

   ```
   $ rpcinfo -p
   ```

   ```
   program vers proto   port
   100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind 
   100000    3   udp    111  rpcbind 
   100000    4   udp    111  rpcbind 
   100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind 
   100000    3   tcp    111  rpcbind 
   100000    4   tcp    111  rpcbind 
   100024    1   udp    612  status 
   100024    1   tcp   1021  status 
   100021    0   udp    843  nlockmgr 
   100021    1   udp    843  nlockmgr 
   100021    3   udp    843  nlockmgr 
   100021    4   udp    843  nlockmgr 
   100021    0   tcp   1017  nlockmgr 
   100021    1   tcp   1017  nlockmgr 
   100021    3   tcp   1017  nlockmgr 
   100021    4   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
   ```
5. Test connection to nfs

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 2049
   ```

   > Trying ::1...
   >   Connected to localhost.
   >   Escape character is '^]'.
6. Create folder to be shared

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/tmp/shared-test
   $ touch ~/tmp/shared-test/works.txt
   ```
7. Add it to /etc/exports

   ```
   $ sudo echo "/Users/user/tmp/shared-test -mapall=-2:-2 -ro" >> /etc/exports
   $ sudo chmod 640 /etc/exports
   ```
8. Make sure /etc/exports is correct

   ```
   $ sudo nfsd checkexports
   ```

## The issue:

```
$ showmount -e
```

```
showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: localhost: RPC failed:: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Bad file descriptor
```

```
$ syslog
```

```
Oct 17 21:56:28 Estebans-MacBook-Pro-2 rpc.lockd[215] : can't contact statd, 100024 RPC: Timed out
--- last message repeated 2 times ---
Oct 17 21:58:29 Estebans-MacBook-Pro-2 syslogd[43] : ASL Sender Statistics
Oct 17 21:59:31 Estebans-MacBook-Pro-2 rpc.lockd[215] : can't contact statd, 100024 RPC: Timed out
Oct 17 22:00:19 Estebans-MacBook-Pro-2 login[1328] : USER_PROCESS: 1328 ttys002
Oct 17 22:00:33 Estebans-MacBook-Pro-2 rpc.lockd[215] : can't contact statd, 100024 RPC: Timed out
```

I can see **rpc.lockd[215] : can't contact statd, 100024 RPC: Timed out** all over, as a recurrent log.

```
$ showmount 127.0.0.1
```

```
showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: 127.0.0.1: RPC: Program not registered
```

Comment: Excellent troubleshooting... have you tried starting the NFS daemon with `launchctl` instead? In macOS Sierra (haven't installed High Sierra yet) I first created `/etc/exports` with contents: `/private/tmp -ro`, then I ran: `sudo launchctl start com.apple.nfsd` and checked the RPC information with `rpcinfo -p` until all daemons were up and running: rpcbind, status (which is in fact rpc.statd), nlockmgr, nfs, mountd and rquotad. It needed a couple of seconds. Then I could mount `/private/tmp` with: `sudo mount -t nfs localhost:/private/tmp /mnt/tmp/` without a problem.

Comment: when doing ```rpcinfo -p``` I only get rpcbind, rpcbind, nlockmgr. I do not see nfs, neither mountd nor rquotad. What should be expected?

Comment: If you followed the steps in my previous comment I'd expect that you see nfs, mountd and rquotad listed in `rpcinfo`'s output. You probably need to disable nfsd with `sudo nfsd disable` (to prevent any conflicts with `launchctl`) and restart your computer, then start nfsd with `launchctl`. I'd recommend that you comment out any existing entries in `/etc/exports`, add a simple export like `/private/tmp -ro` for troubleshooting purposes and test connecting to `localhost`.

Comment: I did ```sudo nfsd disable``` but ```rpcinfo -p``` was showing the same until I restarted the computer. Once I restarted, ```rpcinfo -p``` shows ```rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: rpcinfo: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Broken pipe```. Although, after doing ```sudo launchctl start com.apple.nfsd```, ```rpcinfo -p``` still showing ```rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: rpcinfo: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Broken pipe```

Comment: I think the issue that I see when doing ```showmount -e 127.0.0.1```is because mountd is not launched. If I do ```sudo nfsd -P 1234 start```, that should launch mountd in port 1234, but I do not see it, neither in ```rpcinfo -p``` nor ```nmap localhost```

Comment: I did ```sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist``` and then ```sudo launchctl start com.apple.nfsd```. That brought the same result as ```sudo nfsd start``` for ```rpcinfo -p```, rpcbind, status and nlockmgr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I had some issues with my /etc/hosts file. The suspicion was alert seeing **rpc.lockd[215] : can't contact statd, 100024 RPC: Timed out** all over.

I cleaned up the /etc/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
```

Restarted the service
`sudo nfsd restart`

And finally when doing `showmount -e localhost`:

`Exports list on localhost:
/Users/kiwi/user/shared-test         Everyone`

`rpcinfo -p`

```
   program vers proto   port
    100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100024    1   udp    906  status
    100024    1   tcp   1021  status
    100021    0   udp    730  nlockmgr
    100021    1   udp    730  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp    730  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp    730  nlockmgr
    100021    0   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp   1017  nlockmgr
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100005    1   udp    989  mountd
    100005    3   udp    989  mountd
    100005    1   tcp   1023  mountd
    100005    3   tcp   1023  mountd
    100011    1   udp    636  rquotad
    100011    2   udp    636  rquotad
    100011    1   tcp    999  rquotad
    100011    2   tcp    999  rquotad
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, but what do you mean by cleaning up the hosts file? What was the issue? I have the same problem and I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: @loo3y35 It was a long time ago, but my issue was that my /etc/hosts file had tons of rules (work related) that clashed on how localhost was getting resolved, I can not remember how or which rule exactly.
By clean up the /etc/hosts file, I mean remove all rules except for the default ones. The code snippet in my answer is an example of a clean /etc/hosts file.